# how to set value form input vue js from json

Tags: javascript, vue.js

please have a problem here. I want to display the value from the input form: name and position. but the data is in the form of json.

```
{"id":5,"name":"the name","pos":"the position"}
```

This is template html vue js

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Edit <b>{{name}}</b>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form @submit="edit()" method="post" onclick="return false">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Name</label>
                <input v-model="input.nameInput" type="text" value="?" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Position</label>
                <input v-model="input.posInput" value="?" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is java script of template file vue js

```
<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
        name:'',
        pos:'',
        input:{
          nameInput:'',
          posInput:''
        }
    }
  },
  methods:{
    getEmploye(){
      axios.get('/employes_api/'+this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
        this.name = response.data.name;
        this.pos = response.data.pos;
      });
    },
    edit(){
      axios.put('/employes_api/'+this.$route.params.id, {
        name: this.name,
        pos: this.position,
      }).then(response => {
        this.$route.employe;
      });
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.getEmploye();
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What errors are you getting? can you post your main.js file? there doesn't appear to be any errors here, that method would work to get the json data.

Answer (score 0):

As described in your question, if the data received is

```
{"id":5,"name":"the name","pos":"the position"}
```

then you `getEmploye` method should be :

```
getEmploye(){
  axios.get('/employes_api/'+this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
    this.name = response.name;
    this.pos = response.pos;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

On element’s value, you may use the following to display data you have received from the api:

```
value=“{{name}}”
```

That means you are getting the value from name data.

Also, to test if that works, you may assign first a dummy data/value to name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make two separate variables one for the inputs and the other for the display, just keep the same variable for both, it will be automatically updated on the display and in the inputs while the user is typing, that's the beauty of Vue.

So instead of

```
data(){
    return{
        name:'',
        pos:'',
        input:{
          nameInput:'',
          posInput:''
        }
    }
  },
```

Just keep

```
data(){
    return{
        name:'',
        pos:''
    }
},
```

For the template inputs use :

```
<input v-model="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
...
<input v-model="pos" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

The overall result should look like this :

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Edit <b>{{name}}</b>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form @submit="edit()" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Name</label>
                <input v-model="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Position</label>
                <input v-model="position" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
        name:'',
        pos:''
    }
  },
  methods:{
    getEmploye(){
      axios.get('/employes_api/'+this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
        this.name = response.data.name;
        this.pos = response.data.pos;
      });
    },
    edit(){
      axios.put('/employes_api/'+this.$route.params.id, {
        name: this.name,
        pos: this.pos,
      }).then(response => {
        this.$route.employe;
      });
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.getEmploye();
  }
}
```

Ps : Didn't test the code, if there is any error just let me know

Answer (score -2):

Use `:value=“name”`, e.g `<input :value="name"/>`.